# Given two vectors and its resultant force

Tags: vectors

Given vector a with an angle of 15 degrees from the x-axis, vector b with an angle of 25 degrees from the other side of the x-axis, and 100N as a resultant force, **find the forces applied by the vectors**

Comment: What do you mean by other side of x axis? 25 degrees from negative x axis?

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of forces
$$
F_1 \cos 15 + F_2 \cos 65 = 100
\tag{1}
$$

Law of cosines
$$
 100^2 = F_1^2 + F_2^2 - 2 F_1 F_2 \cos 140
\tag{2}
$$

Try drawing the diagram.